# Compare PropertyInfo name to an existing property in a safe way

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I have a PropertyInfo, and I'd would like to check if it is a specific one. Knowing that its `ReflectedType` is correct, I could do this:

```
bool TestProperty(PropertyInfo prop)
{
    return prop.Name == "myPropertyName";
}
```

The problem is that my property `myPropertyName` could change name in the futur, and I would have no way to realize that the above code just broke.

Is there a safe way to test what I want, probably using Expression ?

Comment: Did you consider using a custom attribute to check if you have found the right property? Or you could use the `nameof` operator.

Comment: `nameof` sounds great, but I'm not using the right version of c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make `Expression` for the property then it is possible to retrieve name from this expression:

```
public static string PropertyName<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
{
    MemberExpression mbody = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (mbody == null)
    {
        //This will handle Nullable<T> properties.
        UnaryExpression ubody = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;

        if (ubody != null)
        {
            mbody = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (mbody == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a MemberExpression", "propertyExpression");
        }
    }

    return mbody.Member.Name;
}
```

Then you can use it in next manner:

```
bool TestProperty(PropertyInfo prop)
{
    return prop.Name == Extensions.PropertyName<TargetClass>(x => x.myPropertyName);;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, `Expression` trees are quite slow. It is probably a good idea to "cache" it in a `static readonly` field... `private static readonly string MyPropertyName = Extensions.PropertyName<TargetClass>(x => x.myPropertyName)`

Comment: @xanatos Great addition. There is many ways to improve performance and it depend on scenarios for `TestProperty` method and initial problem.

Comment: Great, that's the kind of code I had in mind. I don't really understand how UnaryExpression apply here thus. Would you have an example ?

Comment: @xanatos I thought expression evaluation was expensive. But in the above code, that is simply accessing expression members, would that be slow too ?

Comment: @RomainVergnory The expression tree `x => x.myPropertyName` is rebuilt every time you enter the `TestProperty` method. It isn't cached. That expression tree is based on three `Expression` objects (four if the property is a value type) that are rebuilt every time... So every time you call that method, three (four) objects are created.